How can one write unit tests for CSS in a Svelte component?
I have a HelloWorld Svelte component as below:
//
// HelloWorld.svelte
//

<script>
    export let name = 'world';
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<style>
  h1 {
    background-color: #00b5e2;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>


I have configured Vite as the builder and Vitest as the test framework for unit tests. Vitest is configured to use JSDom.
I have written unit tests to test the script and HTML parts of the component using Vitest and @testing-library
How can I write a unit test to verify that the h1 element is assigned the color #fff and background color #00b5e2? An example/guidance would be much appreciated.
I have tried using Quixote but honestly did not quite understand how to integrate it to test Svelte components since Quixote appears to require separate CSS files to be provided to start unit testing whereas for Svelte the CSS is embedded in the "<style>" part of the .svelte file.

You didn't specify your vitest config settings, but if you are using jsdom to run your tests you will be unable to verify the css values in your example. Why? Apparently, the cascade and inheritance behaviors for CSS are not fully implemented in jsdom.
The ideal way to test styling is with an e2e test using an automated browser like playwright. Specifically, the playwright locator function .toHaveCSS is designed to verify styling on any DOM element.
I also found this guide which goes into detail regarding the .toHaveCSS function and recommends some ideas for using it to verify color values.

I configured Vitest to use JSDom (and have updated the question to include this).
I did read up about using Playwright and Cypress but was looking for a more unit-test like setup (that avoided a browser perhaps) instead of an e2e setup.
I appreciate the suggestion though. I was indeed trying out in this way using Cypress while exploring other ways.
